# Drop a row based on empty/blanks values in specific column in final excel file - Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, rows, drop

I am trying to drop rows based on the empty values in a specific column of excel after joining the data for both excels. I have tried some queries mentioned in stack overflow, but the desire results are not achieved. Kindly support and thanks

First Excel File Named: Fileq.xls
Contents are below

| Item | Applied Qty | Reference Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 0 |  |
| Item B | 20 | 18 |
| Item C | 0 |  |
| Item D | 1 |  |
| Item E | 2 |  |

First Excel File Named: Data.xls
Contents are below

| Item | Applied Qty | Reference Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item G | 0 |  |
| Item H | 12 | 13 |
| Item I | 0 |  |
| Item J | 1 | 25 |
| Item K | 2 |  |

Desired Results:-

| Item | Applied Qty | Reference Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item B | 20 | 18 |
| Item H | 12 | 13 |
| Item J | 1 | 25 |

Code I am trying:-

```
import pandas as pd
DATA_DIR = Path.cwd() / r'C:\Python'

excel001 = DATA_DIR / 'Fileq.xls'

excel002 = DATA_DIR / 'Data.xls'

df001 = pd.read_excel(excel001)

df002 = pd.read_excel(excel002)

values001 = df001

values002 = df002

dataframes = [values001, values002]

join = pd.concat(dataframes)

#Tried many different combinations but non are working as below

new_df= join['Reference Qty'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, inplace=True) 

print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very close! Just missing [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) we can pass a `dict` to `replace` so as to *only* `replace` on the `'Reference Qty'` column instead of replacing the entire DataFrame:

```
new_df = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .replace({'Reference Qty': r'^\s*$'}, np.nan, regex=True)
        .dropna(subset=['Reference Qty'])
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     Item  Applied Qty Reference Qty
1  Item B           20          18.0
1  Item H           12          13.0
3  Item J            1          25.0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item': ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C', 'Item D', 'Item E'],
    'Applied Qty': [0, 20, 0, 1, 2],
    'Reference Qty': ['', 18.0, '', '', '']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item': ['Item G', 'Item H', 'Item I', 'Item J', 'Item K'],
    'Applied Qty': [0, 12, 0, 1, 2],
    'Reference Qty': ['', 13.0, '', 25.0, '']
})

new_df = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .replace({'Reference Qty': r'^\s*$'}, np.nan, regex=True)
        .dropna(subset=['Reference Qty'])
)

print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
df.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True)

df.dropna(subset = ["Reference Qty"], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [dropna function](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-drop-empty-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python) from pandas is what you are looking for: